# Why does Typesafe Activator not set up documentation for dependencies in IDEA?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, typesafe-activator, sbt-idea

I've noticed that if I create a new IntelliJ IDEA project with SBT and `gen-idea` It will set up the project structure to have the class jars, source jars and javadocs jars.

However if I use a Typesafe Activator template and run either `gen-idea` from within the web UI or manually via SBT, it only sets up the class jars.

Is downloading and configuring documentation for libraries something that needs to be defined in `build.sbt` or is it some local misconfiguration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the sbt-idea plugin, but the answer to *"Is downloading and configuring documentation for libraries something that needs to be defined in build.sbt or is it some local misconfiguration?"* is yes as described in the official documentation of sbt in [Library Management](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html) under [Download Sources](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html#Download+Sources):

*To have sbt download the dependency’s sources without using an IDE plugin, add `withSources()` to the dependency definition. For API jars, add `withJavadoc()`. For example:*

```
libraryDependencies += 
  "org.apache.felix" % "org.apache.felix.framework" % "1.8.0" withSources() withJavadoc()
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly for all my SBT dependencies and set up IntelliJ properly as well. However, scala itself, not being a dependency, isn't configured. Is that something that can also be defined in build.sbt, or does that look like a `gen-idea` area of reponsibility?

Comment: Why do you bother yourself with the plugin? IDEA supports sbt projects since the release 13 and there are the options to download sources and scaladocs.

Comment: Just ignorance. I thought IDEAs support was just understanding my existing build.sbt. I just tried a project import instead and it took care of everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's different versions of the sbt-idea plugin? Look in your `project/` directory and your global `~/.sbt/0.13` directory for where sbt-idea gets added and see if you have the same version in the two cases.